# how to create multiscreen application in Qt QML

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml

Very simple question.

This is regarding `Qt 4.8.5, QML, QtQuick 1.1`

I cannot understand how screen transitions are happening in QML and how to code.

For simplicity consider I have 3 different screens in 3 different QML files.

```
1.Home Screen
2.Setting Screen
3.Help Screen
all with width: 640 and height:480
```

Each screen in different and has different child inside.

Now I have a button in Home screen to go the Setting Screen which has a back button to come back. And then in both 1 and 2 there is a help button which shows the Help Screen.

**Now how should my main.qml file be???**

for simplicity consider the screens have only the navigation buttons.

**Can someone post me a code.?**

Comment: If you don't understand how to code, you should read Qt's documentation first. You need to learn the toolkit that you're using, rather than ask for the code to be written for you. If you already have, then post your (minimal) code and state what the specific problem is.

Comment: I have just now started to learn. But the documentation is very vague. Yeah they have good details. But details like these are very difficult to find. I just want to know to do basic stuff not advanced.. Thanks! Please suggest if any tutorials available.

Comment: The documentation is actually ample, especially for the needs of a newbie. Rolling your own stack view element is trivial. But you must first learn the language basics, rushing into it is not the best way to learn.

Comment: https://qmlbook.github.io/index.html

Comment: All you really need to get a functional stack view going is a regular `Item`, knowledge of how to create objects dynamically, and how to put them in a JS array so that you can track and manage their visibility and lifetime.

Comment: The problem is i'm stuck with this old `QtQuick 1.1`. because my project specification is such. There is not much features or proper textbooks.. In the new version of Qt everything is smooth and tons of features. Hope i can convince to change to `Qt5`.

Comment: That would be best, qtquick 1 is a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that your app will stay fixed to those 3 screens, you can get away with something as simple as this:

```
Rectangle {
  id: app
  anchors.fill: parent
  Row {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Button {
      text: "settings"
      onClicked: set.visible = true
    }
    Button {
      text: "help"
      onClicked: help.visible = true
    }
  }
}
Rectangle {
  id: set
  anchors.fill: parent
  color: "red"
  visible: false
  Button {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: "close"
    onClicked: set.visible = false
  }
}
Rectangle {
  id: help
  anchors.fill: parent
  color: "blue"
  visible: false
  Button {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: "close"
    onClicked: help.visible = false
  }
}
```

You have all 3 "screens" in a sequence so that the app screen is on the bottom, with settings and help on top. Then you can switch screens by simply controlling the visibility.

If you want a more dynamic solution, follow my hints from the comments to implement a simple stack view, it is quite easy and will be a good exercise to learn QML.

You **definitely don't want** to follow the example of Konstantin T., and it is a mystery why such a flawed example was upvoted in the first place. That approach will destroy your app screen every time you open settings or help, going back you will not go to your previous screen, but to a brand new instance of it, losing all your previous input. Also, putting a mouse area on top of that guarantees you will not be able to interact with any of the screen's element.

Comment: Just one more question. If I have all the screens in separate file. Then controlling them using a C++ code will be easy for debugging or using QML? Which is the professional way?

Comment: @Dannysam you shouldn't really be controlling QML objects from C++, even though it is possible it is more of an anti-pattern. The professional way is to use C++ for core logic and QML for GUI. Then you can interface the public core logic API to be used from QML. The GUI should access the core logic, but not the other way round. Having the screens in different files is recommended if they are big or you plan on reusing them, and having them in separate files allows to use them as encapsulated components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-loader.html) element. It is used to dynamically load visual QML components. It can load a QML file (using the source property) or a Component object (using the sourceComponent property).

**For example:**

```
Item {
    width: 200; height: 200
    Loader { 
        id: pageLoader
        source = "Page1.qml"
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: pageLoader.source = "Page2.qml"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u check this question.[link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/43431/multi-screen-qml-app/2)  Loader is a heavy task, and in QtQuick 1.1 is there a stack view? If not how do i proceed?

Comment: @Dannysam There aren't StackView in Qt 4.8 it is included only in Qt 5.7. 
You can try load your screen from the [Component element](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-component.html) using `Loader::sourceComponent` , I'm not sure, but it can be faster.

Comment: This won't work well. This will destroy the previous screen when you load a new one, which is NOT how stack views work. When you go back to the previous screen, you will realize all your changes have been destroyed, because it is not the view you worked with before opening a sub-view, but a brand new and empty one.

Comment: ddriver right. This is not the best solution. But in some cases it can be good enough.

Comment: " in some cases it can be good enough" - not in the case of the question. Also, that mouse area will block everything underneath, it would be impossible to interact with the loaded element.

Comment: In case when you not have enough RAM, keep component in RAM is the worst solution. At first, Danny sam just asked, how to change screen in QML. I give him a simple way to do this. No mystery here.